# node_modules disappear from docker-compose container after initial docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I am running node.js on several docker containers and volume mounting my working directory so that I can use nodemon to rebuild my code as I make changes on my host. I have followed all of the instructions for volume mounting code from the host and separately mounting my node_modules file inside my docker container.

The problem that I have is that the initial docker build works great however when nodemon rebuilds my code, my node_modules file is no longer there and the build fails. Restarting my container fixes the issue, but again, I cannot save my files and have nodemon rebuild the code.

What am I doing wrong:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /srv
ADD ./src/package.json .
RUN npm install
ADD ./src .
RUN ls

FROM node:10.12.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /srv .
RUN ls
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install nodemon -g
EXPOSE 3001
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    networks:
      - site
    build: ./api/
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      STAGE: "local"
      PORT: 3001
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: [ "pm2-runtime", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

I have tried everything I can think of...

- removing my build container in my dockerfile
- removing pm2 and starting node directly.
- moving npm install to command in my docker file
- removing package.json and clearing npm cache before npm install

Comment: in your docker-compose file why it is `- /app/node_modules`. Is there anything missed?

Comment: Can you inspect the docker container and check if node_modules is there in root or not

Comment: @Chandan It is in the root when docker-compose initially builds the container or when the container restarts, but not after that.

Comment: @JefinStephan That is the volume mount for my node_modules folder, if that line wasn't there the volume mount would mount the entire src file and since there is no node_modules file on my host, it would be erased from the docker container.

Comment: @JensenS i got your idea. `/app/node_modules` is the path in the container. But to where it will bind? We should give `<WorkingDirPath>:<PathInContainer>` to bind two volumes. Here, there is only `<PathInContainer>`.

Comment: @JefinStephan That line binds the node_modules folder only to the container. That way you do not have to have node_modules installed on your host. https://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html